# Add packages to a Live USB

Tags: live-usb

Ubuntu doesn't include the drivers (package `firmware-b43-installer`) for my network card by default. So each time I use a Live USB with Ubuntu I have to connect my pc to a wired network and then install the package I need. Then I can connect it to the wifi.

How can I add that package to the Live USB without make it persistent (I don't want my usb drive to record the files I have created or downloaded)?

Comment: To clarify, you want the b43 firmware installed to persist on the live usb every time you use it but not have any other persistence?  Or do you want some other solution?

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes, that solution

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu into the USB pendrive (install it like into an internal drive but to the USB pendrive - which works well in a fast USB 3 pendrive). It is possible to install the broadcom driver like into any installed system.

If you avoid proprietary drivers it will be very portable, but in this case you need the broadcom driver, which is proprietary. I suggest that you test if such a system can do what you want it to do.

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)